# jQuery toggle class of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this fancy jQuery function to toggle some classes:

```
$( "#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub a" ).click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul.sub").toggleClass( "visible" );
});
```

This does not work, because my HTML-structure is a little bit different:

```
<div id="main-nav>
    <nav class="menu-wrapper">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                <ul class="sub"><li><a href="#">Dolor Sit</a></li></ul>
            <li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

As you can the, the `ul.sub` is not a child of the `.menu li.has-sub a` but of the `.menu li.has-sub` (without a). Is there a way to select the child of **THIS** li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.next()`

```js
$("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub a").click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul.sub").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-nav">
  <nav class="menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Dolor Sit</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! Like this simple way. Thank you!

Comment: @Pugazh: this will break when there is modification in dom structure.

Answer (score 2):

Targeted two anchor elements are sibling and child respectively of `ul.sub`. You need to traverse to closest `li.has-sub` and then find ul element in it:

```
$( "#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub a" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.has-sub').find("ul.sub").toggleClass( "visible" );
});
```

```js
$( "#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub a" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.has-sub').find("ul.sub").toggleClass( "visible" );
});
```

```css
.visible{background : grey}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-nav">
    <nav class="menu-wrapper">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                <ul class="sub"><li><a href="#">Dolor Sit</a></li></ul>
            <li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine as well! Thank you, Milind :)

Comment: @Rajesh: not in case of anchor sibling element.